# ERD for an online charity/donation application database

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I've been having some trouble setting up the database relationships for a Vue.js/ExpressJS project, I'm looking for some advice on it please.

My ERD at the moment:

[image: Online shop ERD]

My main concern is with the user messaging relationships/setup. The many-many relationship between 'Users' and 'Room' doesn't seem right, but I don't know how to do it differently, there's always going to be many (2+) users in a conversation, and users can of course always participate in many conversations. I feel like I might be thinking about it all wrong. Is the 'Conversations' table redundant even, should messages just relate to 'Room'?

Also, should I have separate tables for item categories and quality, or just have them in the Items table as types/strings that are limited to specific words by the application?

If there's anything else as well that anyone notices that I should or shouldn't do, please do let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea how a conversation relates to a donation.  Please explain how your application is supposed to work.

Comment: It's an application where people or businesses can put up items that they don't want/need anymore, like food, furniture, clothes etc, offering them to the local community. People can see what items have been listed for donation, and can contact the donator regarding the goods.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, person A calls your organization and offers to donate a table.  You list the table on your website.  Person A has to hold on to the table until and unless person B contacts person A and gets the table from them.  How is this any better than Goodwill where person A can drop off the table and not be bothered further?  Also, assuming you build this website, what happens when person C contacts person A about the table because person A didn't contact your organization to let them know that person B already got the table?

Comment: So first of all this is for a college project, so it's not going to be public or used in practice ever. In theory though, people use the website/application themselves, they don't contact me or anyone else to put things up. So person A wants to get rid of a table, if they bring it to Goodwill (Not a thing in my country by the way), they have to go through the process of transporting a table, but on this application they would just list their item and if  person B wants it, they can sort out transportation between themsevles, maybe person A doesn't have to do any transportation.

Comment: I don't know a US equivalent, but it's similar to local marketplace websites, like Donedeal.ie for me, though with an emphasis on giving things away rather than selling.